# Code below is to check if cell value in one sheet A Matches value in Sheet B then copy entire row into Sheet C

Tags: excel, vba

```
Dim k As Long
Dim n As Integer
Dim x As Long
Dim y As Integer
Dim g As Integer


x = Sheets("DataSheet").Range("c3", Sheets("DataSheet").Range("c3").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count

y = Sheets("DataSheet").Cells(x, 3).Value

k = Sheets("Criteria").Range("b2", Sheets("Criteria").Range("b2").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count

n = Sheets("Criteria").Cells(k, 2).Value

For n = 2 To k

If n = y Then

Sheets("DataSheet").Row(n + 1).Copy Sheets("Main").Cells(n + 2, 1).Paste

End If
Next n
```

Tried using index match excel formula.

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Seems there are several problems in your code. Not clear that which cells do you want to compare? Pls. add sample data to your post to show the source and the expected result. BTW. variable `n` is set to a value then in the next line use it as a loop counter.